# How to disable to login screen shortcut (Cmd+Alt+L)

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac

I'm trying to find where this shortcut is being configured under Snow Leopard but I simply can not. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: basically to disable it or at least change the default to something else that is overlapping with an app shortcut

Comment: What does the shortcut currently do?

Comment: Nikos, please provide more information or I fear this question will end up voted to a close...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but Safari uses CMD+Alt+L for the downloads window.

Also, I used to use LockMyScreen (which doesn't work in Snow Leopard anymore), and it's shortcut is showing in my Mac as CMD+Alt+L.

I went to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, then looked in Application Shortcuts.